# How to move and rotate an image at the same time in Corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to throw throwing stars in a game.
I can move the star with

```
bulletTransition[bulletCounter] = transition.to(bullets[bulletCounter], {x=-250, time=2000, onComplete=function(self)
        if(self~=nil) then 
            display.remove(self)
        end
        end})
```

I know I can rotate things with

```
transition.to( bullets[bulletCounter], { rotation = bullets[bulletCounter].rotation-360, time=2000, onComplete=spinImage } )
```

But how do I make the translation and rotation happen at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call both at same time in a single transition. Just like:

```
local rect = display.newRect(300,100,50,50) -- Create object

transition.to(rect, {x=-250, rotation = rect.rotation-360,time=2000,} ) -- Transition call
```